# How to extract text between two words using str_extract?

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to extract a string in between two fixed strings. Specifically, I want the string, which is over multiple lines, between "Address:" and "This grant". Here is an example:

```
Address:
The PowerPool Corp                                                  
1434 Holyfried Route, Unit A                                                 
Melope, VA 21151

This grant is issued
```

I tried the following code, but it does not work:

```
str_extract(test_case, "(?<=Address:\n)[^\\n]+")
```

which outputs

```
[1] "The PowerPool Corp"
```

How do I get all three lines of the address?

Comment: `[^\\n]+` will match one or more characters that aren't a linebreak. As soon as it hits a linebreak, it's done. (Just explaining why this method doesn't work - there's already an answer showing a fix.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the matches without the dotall mode by first matching Address: and then capture in group 1 all the lines that do not start with "This grant"

```
Address:\r?\n((?:(?!This grant\b).*(?:\r?\n|$))*)
```

In parts

- `Address:\r?\n` Match Address: and a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!This grant\b).*` Match the whole lines if what is directly on the right is not "This grant"
    - `(?:\r?\n|$)` Match either a newline or assert the end of the string
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat to get all the lines
- `)`

For example

```
library(stringr)
test_case <- "Address:
The PowerPool Corp
1434 Holyfried Route, Unit A
Melope, VA 21151

This grant is issued"

str_match(test_case, "Address:\\r?\\n((?:(?!This grant\\b).*(?:\\r?\\n|$))*)")[,2]
```

Output

```
[1] "The PowerPool Corp\n1434 Holyfried Route, Unit A\nMelope, VA 21151\n\n"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a8JoPe/1) | [R demo](https://rextester.com/LOGWX6645)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sub` in base R, seems to work fine :

```
cat(sub("Address:(.*)This grant.*", "\\1", test_case))

#The PowerPool Corp                                                  
#1434 Holyfried Route, Unit A                                                 
#Melope, VA 21151
```

Using `cat` to show the output in a formatted way.

**data**

```
test_case <- "Address:
The PowerPool Corp                                                  
1434 Holyfried Route, Unit A                                                 
Melope, VA 21151

This grant is issued"
```

Answer (score 1):

In `str_extract` the `.` won't match line terminators (`\n`) unless you tell it to. Use the `regex` *modifier function* with argument `dotall = T` to match over multiple lines. Note that I've also fixed your regular expression by removing `[^\\n]+` and adding `.*` plus a lookbehind `(?=\n\nThis grant)`:

```r
str_extract(test_case,
            regex("(?<=Address:\n).*(?=\n\nThis grant)",
                  dotall = T
                  )
            )

# [1] "The PowerPool Corp\n1434 Holyfried Route, Unit A\nMelope, VA 21151"
```

There might also be simpler/faster ways to deal with this. For example, if you know that the first a last lines are always junk you can split at the `\n` and then select the relevant lines or drop the irrelevant lines, i.e. `str_split(test_case, "\n")[[1]][2:4]` vs. `str_split(test_case, "\n")[[1]][-c(1, 5, 6)]`.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262841/6553328) is simple and good, just in case, we would have had multiple addresses, maybe,

```
Address:\\s*(.*?)\\s*This grant\\b
```

and a replacement of `\\1` would be an option too.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rCWLK/1/)